# Convert from base 10 to an arbitrary radix with proper sign extend

Tags: base-conversion, radix, sign-extension

I was wondering if there's a formal way to properly sign extend base-10 numbers in an arbitrary base when converting. For example, if I had -256 in base 10, how would I properly sign extend the result in base 7 (or base n) without assuming a fixed length for the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> The radix complement of an n digit number y in radix b is, by definition, b<sup>n</sup> − y
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Numeric_complements

When we sign-extend the number to `n+1` digits, the new representation for the value is

> b<sup>n+1</sup> − y = b*b<sup>n</sup> − y = b<sup>n</sup> − y + (b-1)b<sup>n</sup>

As **b-1** is the *largest digit in base b* and **b<sup>n</sup>** contains *all 0s in the n least significant digits* (i.e. 100..0 with n zeros in base b), **(b-1)b<sup>n</sup>** is simply a number with `b-1` followed by n zeros. The remaining part (**b<sup>n</sup> − y**) is the old n-digit radix complement in base n

So basically a 1-digit sign-extension in base `b` is just about prepending the digit `b-1` to the left of the old value. With mathematical induction this will applies to any values of n

For example:

- -256 in base 10:

  - 3 digits: 744
  - 4 digits: 9744
  - 5 digits: 99744
- -256 in base 7:

  - [3 digits: 153](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(7%5E3-256)+in+base+7)
  - [4 digits: 6153](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(7%5E4-256)+in+base+7)
  - [5 digits: 66153](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(7%5E5-256)+in+base+7)